# Worker Unable to query / access Mongoose Model

Tags: node.js, web-worker, node-worker-threads

I tried importing the Mongoose model directly in the worker like :

```
  Worker, isMainThread, parentPort, workerData
} = require('worker_threads');

if (isMainThread) {
  module.exports = function parseJSAsync(script) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const worker = new Worker(__filename, {
        workerData: null
      });
      worker.on('message', resolve);
      worker.on('error', reject);
      worker.on('exit', (code) => {
        if (code !== 0)
          reject(new Error(`Worker stopped with exit code ${code}`));
      });
    });
  };
} else {
  const MyModel = require("../models/MyModel.js");
  const data = await MyModel.find();
}
```

Query didn't run! But no exceptions or errors

So then I tried passing the model as WorkerData from the main thread :

```
const {
  Worker, isMainThread, parentPort, workerData
} = require('worker_threads');

const MyModel = require("../models/MyModel.js");

if (isMainThread) {
  module.exports = function parseJSAsync(script) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const worker = new Worker(__filename, {
        workerData: MyModel
      });
      worker.on('message', resolve);
      worker.on('error', reject);
      worker.on('exit', (code) => {
        if (code !== 0)
          reject(new Error(`Worker stopped with exit code ${code}`));
      });
    });
  };
} else {
  
  const MyModel = workerData;
  const data = await MyModel.find();
}
```

This time I got the exception :

```
DOMException [DataCloneError]: function model(doc, fields, skipId) {
      model.hooks.execPreSync('createModel', doc);
      if (!(this insta...<omitted>... } could not be cloned.
    at new Worker (internal/worker.js:144:17)
```

What do I do to be able to access the Database from the Worker thread?

Should I establish a separate connection to the DB within the thread using :
`mongoose.connect()` ?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if you're resolved your problem, but i had the same, for people that arrive here, the solution is:
as a fact (like @jackOfAll supposed): **establish connection with DB**